# MySQL TIMESTAMPDIFF function doesn't return expected result

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT
  M.strMemID                                          AS 'Member ID',
  M.strMemLastname                                    AS 'Last Name',
  M.STRMEMFIRSTNAME                                   AS 'First Name',
  M.strMemMiddlename                                  AS 'Middle Name',
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, m.dtmMemBirthday, CURRENT_DATE) AS 'Age'
FROM TBLMEMBER M
WHERE m.strMemID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT m.strmemid
                         FROM tblmember m, tblmemberministry mm, tblpositionmemberministry pmm
                         WHERE m.strMemID = mm.strMMMemID AND mm.strmemmincode = pmm.strpmmmemmincode AND (
                           pmm.strPMMCode = 'POS041' OR PMM.STRPMMCODE = 'POS009' OR PMM.STRPMMCODE = 'POS010' OR
                           PMM.STRPMMCODE = 'POS012' OR PMM.STRPMMCODE = 'POS017' OR PMM.STRPMMCODE = 'POS021' OR
                           PMM.STRPMMCODE = 'POS028' OR PMM.STRPMMCODE = 'POS031' OR PMM.STRPMMCODE = 'POS037' OR
                           PMM.STRPMMCODE = 'POS039') AND mm.dtmMMDateQuit IS NULL AND pmm.dtmpmmdateto IS NULL AND
                               TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, m.dtmMemBirthday, CURRENT_DATE) > 30);
```

This is my code. Please ignore the confusing subquery. My objective is to display members with `age > 30`. I'm using the `TIMESTAMPDIFF`. But this query returns as well as those with age under 30. Can anyone help me?

Comment: edit to lower case

Answer (score 0):

My bad guys. I did not see that my `TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, m.dtmMemBirthday, CURRENT_DATE) > 30` is inside my Sub Query. Solved Now guys! Thanks anyways.